# Log user authentication in grails/acegi

Tags: grails, spring-security

where can I put a println in order to register a user's successful authentication in grails using acegi ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event callback, see http://grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Acegi+Events